# What might a CN filter be in the context of comet watching? Is it showing dust, or gas, or something else?

Tags: spectroscopy

In [this post](http://wirtanen.astro.umd.edu/46P/46P_status.shtml) on the [website for the Comet Wirtanen Observing Campaign](http://wirtanen.astro.umd.edu/) at wirtanen.astro.umd.edu, there's mention of a CN filter being used to observe the comet, and this cool GIF.

What exactly is a CN filter? What wavelengths does it pass? Where can I read more about it? Why is it showing a spiral shape of stuff being emitted from comet 46P? Is this comet dust, gas, something else?

GIF:

[image]

[image: http://wirtanen.astro.umd.edu/46P/46P_status.shtml#brightness_plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CN filter [shows abundances of cyanogen](http://wirtanen.astro.umd.edu/46P/CN_filter_test.shtml), a molecule with the structure $(\mathrm{CN})_2$. Cyanogen emission lines at 387 nm allow us to study gas in the coma of a comet, telling us more about its structure, properties and outgassing. Other gases, like $\mathrm{OH}$, $\mathrm{NH}$ and $\mathrm{C}_2$, also give away a lot of information about a comet, but the often-strong cyanogen lines are a good tool.

The mechanism behind cyanogen production from parent gases isn't entirely clear, although [a number of theories have been proposed](https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/comet/news65.html). For instance, cyanogen could be released by icy grains undergoing sublimation, or by the decomposition of more complex molecules.

Comment: I was surprised to find out that comets were (often) green, then surprised that that was because of C₂ which I'd never heard of, now I'm surprised to hear about cyanogen, never heard of the stuff either!

Comment: The common emission lines of comets are C2, C3, NH, CN and OH as shown in this [spectrum of Comet Hyakutake](https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/comet/hyakutake/news19.html). We use narrowband filters centered on these wavelengths, plus a continuum filter in the red to remove the background, to isolate the gas emission from the dust (which is mostly what you see in wider filters)

Comment: @astrosnapper the extent of my understanding of C2 is in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan_band

Comment: Yes, that's the stuff